OpenLayers access JS function on map from Bootstrap modal
I want to add new points (trees) on an Openlayers map.
The points are added first to a temporary layer (temp) where they can be dragged to the right position using a circle with cross inside (tCross). On dragend a Modal window opens where the user can add additional information.
Beside the possibility to save the data, the Modal has a button that fires the JS function clearLayer(). This function should close the Modal and destroy the added point on the temporary layer. The modal closes fine, but I'm unable to clear the temporary layer. I get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: temp is not defined".
var temp = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector()
  });

var tCross = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
      }),
      radius: 50,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2,
      }),
    }),
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
      radius: 10,
      radius2: 0,
      points: 4,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2,
      }),
    }),
  }),
];


// Longtouch interaction using ol-ext from http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/
var longtouch = new ol.interaction.LongTouch({
  pixelTolerance: 5,
  
  // Handle longtouch > create a new feature
  handleLongTouchEvent: function(e) {
    var f = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(e.coordinate));
    f.setStyle(tCross);
    temp.getSource().addFeature(f);
    
  // deactivate longtouch to prevent to add a second feature 
  map.getInteractions().forEach(function(interaction) {
     if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.LongTouch) {
     interaction.setActive(false);
     }
  }, this); 
  
  // allow feature to be moved on map   
    var dragInteraction = new ol.interaction.Translate({
          features: new ol.Collection([f]),
    });
    
  // on translateend open myModal-window with form to add attributes to feature and save to database or just close the modal and clear the temporary layer. 
    dragInteraction.on('translateend',function(){
    var latlng = ol.proj.transform(this.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
        document.getElementById("lat").value = latlng[1];
        document.getElementById("lng").value = latlng[0];
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    },f);

    map.addInteraction(dragInteraction);
  }
});  // End longtouch 

// add longtouch to map
map.addInteraction(longtouch);


// close modal form and delete circle on map
function clearLayer() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide'); // works fine
    temp.getSource().clear();    // Uncaught ReferenceError: temp is not defined

On the modal form the function clearLayer() is called from a button:
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="clearLayer();">Clear Layer</button>


As the code is presented in the question, it should work. Since it's not complete code to reproduce the error, it's impossible to say why it doesn't work for you.

Ok, this is fine to hear. As the whole code is quite huge, I'll have to prepare a simplified dummy, that I could post here.
